# azure table storage get the data with condition satisfying on a field other than PK or RK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

**My Process**

1. I store the data in Azure Table Storage
2. its huge ==> every second\minute data gets inserted to Table Storage from device.
3. Basically Data from the device is stored into the TableStorage.
4. So the TableStorage has `PK,RK,Timestamp,Vale,TimeReceived` fields.
   Here `TimeReceived` registers the time the device has sent the data and as it is  `Timestamp` registers the time the data was inserted.

**My Requirement**

The latest time in `TimeReceived` should be fetched each time for display on Dashboard.

**My Query**

I will not be knowing the RK or PK to retrieve the latest value that has the latest `TimeRecieved`. 
What is the best way to get this?

**Update**

1. The Table Storage has the  fields `PK,RK,Timestamp,Value,TimeReceived`
2. `PK` has values specific to different signals. So each Partition will have  signal ID as the value.
3. `RK` will take the calculated value  `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`
4. The value for `TimeReceived` will be received from the device.
5. The value for `Value` too will be received from the device.
6. My system displays a Dashboard, which shows the latest value\time received for all the signals of a device.

**My Problem**

So to display the latest value on the Dashboard I need to query each Partition in the TableStorage to get data that has the latest value registered in `TimeReceived`.

As per my reading I understand without PK & RK in query there will be performance issue. Kindly let me know the best\right way to get the latest data as per the value in `TimeReceived`.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your design. This guide will help you make the best out of Azure Table Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide.

Comment: @GauravMantri Can you please give the change needed to make, that might help in my scenario?

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) How does your PartitionKey and RowKey looks like currently and 2) Describe your querying patterns i.e. how you would like to query the data. Only after that I will be able to suggest any changes. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated my Q with my app data design\process.

Comment: Thank you! Let me provide one possible solution in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you need to display the latest values from all the devices, one possible solution would be to store multiple copies of the same data.

In your current design, you have set the `PartitionKey` as the device identifier and the `RowKey` as reverse ticks (excellent decision BTW), what I would suggest is that you keep on saving like this but add one more entry for the same data.

However this time you will reverse the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` i.e. your `PartitionKey` will contain the reverse ticks and `RowKey` will contain the device id.

To reduce the number of partitions, one thing you could do is create a partition with a minute frequency i.e. for each minute, you will create a new partition. Since each device is sending the data per second, you could suffix the device id value with a GUID so that there are no duplicate entries for a device in a minute.

So your entity design to cover your query scenario would be:

```
PartitionKey -> (DateTime.Max.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d20")
RowKey -> Device Id + Guid (to randomize)
DeviceId -> Store the device id as an attribute
TimeReceived -> Store the time when the data was received
Value -> Value received
```

For PartitionKey, you can also use the following formula:

```
PartitionKey -> (DateTime.Max.Ticks - TimeReceived.Ticks).ToString("d20")
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Seems to be really helpful. I'll analyze on this and get back to you, while re-designing, on my queries that I'd have on the existing structure & data queries. _But as a quick question==> Currently I query the TableStorage to fetch the historical data, ~~>for a selected period of time  ~~>for a selected device's signal . In this case can I continue to have my existing table too along with the one you have proposed to accommodate historical searches & to minimize re-work?

Comment: Regarding your question, yes your current approach would work because you're using `PartitionKey` (i.e. device id) in your query so the scan will be restricted to a particular partition.

Comment: How can I achieve creating  new partition for each minute?  i.e. What is the best efficient way to implement it ? Please suggest.

Comment: can you suggest an efficient way of for creating new partitions as per your suggestion `To reduce the number of partitions, one thing you could do is create a partition with a minute frequency i.e. for each minute, you will create a new partition.`